# Why my OpenGL texture are painted in pink?

Tags: android, opengl-es, webrtc, textures

I setup `webrtc` on my android (peer to peer video chat). When I draw texture that comes from the local camera, everything is fine, but when I try to draw texture that comes from the remote smartphone then I have a pink image, something like this :

[image]

on `webrtc` i just do this to get the remote stream:

```
  mRemoteVideoTrack = getRemoteVideoTrack();
  mRemoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
  mRemoteVideoTrack.addSink(mRemoteProxyVideoSink);

  private VideoTrack getRemoteVideoTrack() {
    for (RtpTransceiver transceiver : mPeerConnection.getTransceivers()) {
      MediaStreamTrack track = transceiver.getReceiver().track();
      if (track instanceof VideoTrack) {
        return (VideoTrack) track;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and I get the **texture id** in the `mRemoteProxyVideoSink` :

```
  private class RemoteProxyVideoSink implements VideoSink {

    @Override
    synchronized public void onFrame(VideoFrame frame) {
       VideoFrame.TextureBuffer textureBuffer = (VideoFrame.TextureBuffer) frame.getBuffer();
       mTextureID = textureBuffer.getTextureId();
       .. draw mTextureID (in UI thread because onFrame is not fired in UI thread) ...
    }

  }
```

Any idea why my textures are painted in Pink?

Comment: It seems local camera and smartphone use different image formats (RGB, RGBA, BGR, ABGR, etc)

Comment: @Ripi2, thanks but how to handle this?

Comment: @loki You can do it in a fragment shader. For example, something like `gl_FragColor = yourColor.zyxw;`. Or you could use `glTexParameter*` function to set the `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_*` parameters, if you're targeting GL ES 3.

Comment: @Reaper I think it's something else because when I move the camera, sometime  the frame is paint correctly (ut just for one frame) !

Comment: @loki You could probably get some info by debugging with, for example, GAPID. Also, are you sure that it's not in the YUV format?

Comment: @Reaper: I found another problem, to make think more clear i create a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564583/how-to-draw-the-opengl-texture-retrieved-by-remotevideotrack